# issue with adding mysql FOREIGN KEY to a table

Tags: mysql

I have a problem to add a Foreign key to a table. I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE Child
ADD FOREIGN KEY (pc_id)
REFERENCES Parent_Carer(pc_id);
```

, but it does not add the key. The structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Parent_Carer (
pc_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pc_title CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
pc_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pc_lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
pc_phone VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
pc_address1 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
pc_address2 VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
pc_town VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
pc_postcode VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL) ;


CREATE TABLE Child(
child_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
pc_id INT NOT NULL,
child_fname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
child_lname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
child_dob DATE NOT NULL,
child_gender ENUM ('F','M') DEFAULT 'F' NOT NULL);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get any error? If not, the key should be created. If so, please provide the error.

Comment: Is the table of type 'InnoDB'?

Comment: Both tables Are InnoDB. And the Query browser does not give any error just: 1 row affected by the last command no results returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using to display the Foreign Key?  You need to use one of the following:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name;
```

or

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'tbl_name';
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Sorry, but i dont really get the question about displaying FK.

Comment: Your question says that the FK is not displayed - I want to verify what you are using to 'see' the FK on the table.

Comment: Thaks, but i want just to add the FK to the Child Table

Comment: But I suspect it is being added and just cannot see it.

Comment: Well, perhaps it is the case, but the Query Browser Editing window does not display the key symbol with (pc_id). Sadly.